# How to condense a bunch of consecutive blank lines into a single blank line?

Tags: java

I'm reading input from a separate file and Im having trouble figuring out how to condense a bunch of blank lines and instead just print one line. For example, if my input file has two paragraphs separated by 14 blank lines, the paragraphs should then be separated by one blank line instead of 14 blank lines as the output.

Comment: What have you tried?  As a hint, if you read the entire file into a single `String`, the section of the that has the 14 blank lines will look like `\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n`, but should look like `\n\n` instead.

Comment: When you read a blank line, if the previous input line was blank, don't output it. Just read the next.

Comment: Come on now, at least show us your attempt. Otherwise you're only cheating yourself out of a learning experience. As a general rule, when asking a question here, you should always show what you've tried and explain how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you read line by line, examine each line to see if it's blank (matches regex `^\s*$`, or `line.trim().isEmpty()`). When an input line is blank set a boolean, say `seenBlankLine` to true. On subsequent blank lines if the boolean is true, don't process the line. Remember to set the boolean to false when you encounter a non-blank line.

Answer (score 0):

Read char by char and avoid repeating **carriage returns** and **newlines**:

```
InputStream is = null;
char c; 
int i;

try {
   is = new FileInputStream('/path/to/file');

   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
   while ((i = is.read()) != -1) {
       c = (char)i;

       if (c == '\n' || c == '\r') {
           int length = sb.length();
           if (length == 0 || (length != 0 && sb.charAt(length - 1) != '\n')) {
               sb.append(c);
           }
       } else {
           sb.append(c);
       }     
   }
} catch (Exception e) {
   ...
}
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: Yours is a very low-level solution. I think that a higher level solution would be better, such as using a StringBuilder, a Scanner, and a while loop, and calling `continue` where needed. Doing this I'll bet would cut this code by more than 60% and at the same time make it much more readable, adaptable, and debuggable. Also, why use a StringBuffer instead of StringBuilder. Where could there be a possible threading issue with this local variable?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Right! I was just trying to show something different! :)